# Flutter/Android Studio use key from another project to sign my relaese

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I'm using command `flutter build appbundle --no-shrink --verbose` to create an app bundle.

When I upload my app bundle (let's call APP-A) to Google Play, I'm getting the following error.

***Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again: SHA1: 66:3B:A1.....:CF:B3.***

So I do a `./gradlew signingreport` to see all the keys under my app. And I don't see any key has the footprint of 66:3B:A1.....:CF:B3.

So I checked another app (let's call App-B) that have been released, and it was released with key containing the footprint  66:3B:A1.....:CF:B3.*, and the key was located at `/Users/user1/key.jks`

So go back to APP-A, and search for "key.jks" across all files, and I didn't find anything, and I have the gradle file like this:

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('/Users/user1/key91.jks')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }

        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

and key.properties file:

```
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/Users/user1/app_a.jks
```

So I wonder is there anything inside Android Studio overwritten my configuration here? Or any global environment variable cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try clearing your browser cookies and try again. Happened to me on several times and this works most of the time.